# Recur on children in an object hierarchy in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following problem:

```
(def relations1 
  '((child-of peter carl) 
    (child-of carl herb)

    (peter x 0 y 0 age 6) 
    (carl  x 1 y 1 age 36) 
    (herb  x 2 y 2 age 66)))
```

If a parent moves then the child is moved by the same distance, so if the new relations state that herb and peter have moved, then i want to update the children that are not present in relation2 by the same offset, but those that are present I will leave them alone. So in the next phase:

```
(def relations2 
  '((herby2 x 3 y 2.5 age 66) 
    (pete2  x 0 y 0   age 6)))
```

I have first matched relations1 with those in relation2:

```
(def matches 
  '( ((herb x 2 y 2 age 66) 
      (herb2 x 3 y 2.5 age 66)), 

     ((peter x 0 y 0 age 6)
      (peter2 x 0 y 0 age 6))))
```

I want to go through the matched ones, update their own new positions (while keeping their prev names and age) and recursively check if they have any children to update their positions as well. I tried it but got pretty much stuck on how to recurse on the children too:

```
(def update-parents [matches, relations1]
(loop [rest matches
       all relations1
       result ()]
 (if (empty? rest)
     result
     (let [[head & others] rest
            r1 (first head)
            r2 (second head)
            exists (map first r2)
            children (map second (filter #(and (= (first r1) (last %)) (= 'child-of (first %))) all))] 
          (if (some #(= (first r1) %) exists)
               (recur others (concat (update r1 r2) (recur ???)); if it is already there, update position and its children's
               ; if it's not there, then ignore

)
```

So the end result should be this

```
(def result 
  '((herb  x 3 y 2.5 age 66)
    (peter x 0 y 0   age 6) 
    (carl  x 2 y 1.5 age 36) ))
```

I have two main issues:

1. children returns a list of children, so i need to filter relations1 by those that are in this list
2. how do i recur on the children? do I need to use another loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove things from a list (i.e., make a new list without those things) by putting the things-to-remove into a *set* and using `(remove #(contains? the-set %) the-list)` or, more idiomatically, `(remove the-set the-list)` because a set operates as a function.  ("Filtering" works likewise but *keeps* the things the predicate agrees to.)

The `loop`...`recur` special form will recur only from tail position, which could be a challenge for the given problem.  But if you don't require tail-call optimization, a function may simply call itself.

In any case, if you want to use recursion of any kind, you want a tree-shaped data structure in which every node is similar to the root.  The "bag of facts" in `relation1` will be hard to work with.

Check out `clojure.walk` and `clojure.zip` as canned solutions for tree data structures.

P.S. It might also help to work at a REPL, in a "bottom up" way, tackling the ingredients before the casserole as it were.

Comment: Thanks! But in order to get `the-set` I would need to do a filter first right? Also, should i maintain a tree where i traverse the latest relationN set and update the tree with the 'child-of' relations first, so that its easier to find their children?

Comment: `(remove the-set the-list)` does not seem to work for e.g. `(def the-set '(pete jo)) (def the-list '(alvin))` it gives me an error `clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn`

Comment: I found out how it works, you need to put `(remove (set the-set) the-list)` for it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675859/remove-one-set-from-another-in-clojure