# Remove one set from another in Clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(def mine '(a b c))
(def yours '(a b))
(remove yours mine)
 ; should return (c)
```

I was advised to use remove in another thread but it doesn't work.
Anyone can advise?

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/difference

Comment: Do you want to remove every element in `yours` from `mine` or every element in `mine` from `yours`? This question needs to be clarified in my opinion. Why should it return `(b c)` and not just `(c)`?

Comment: I just want to be able to remove one from the other - i would be able to swap them if it's the other way round. Sorry, the return is a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove from `mine` every element that also exists in `yours`, there are a few approaches. You can convert the lists to sets and use [difference](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/difference), like this:

```
(require '[clojure.set :refer [difference]])

(def mine '(a b c))
(def yours '(a b))

(difference (set mine) (set yours))
;; => #{c}
```

But this does not preserve the order of elements that remain from `mine`. If you want to preserve the order, you can instead use [remove](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove). To do that, we first define a `yours?` predicate that will return true for an element iff that element occurs in `yours`:

```
(def yours-set (set yours))
(def yours? (partial contains? yours-set))
```

If our set `yours` only contains *truthy* values like that are neither `nil` nor `false`, we could define it like `(def yours? (set yours))` since a set implements the [IFn](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html) interface but this approach will not work if `yours` contains elements such as `nil` or `false` as @amalloy pointed out.

```
(remove yours? mine)
;; => (c)
```

The above code means that we remove every element from `mine` for which `yours?` evaluates to true. Yet another, more verbose approach, is to use the opposite of remove, that is [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter), and passing in the opposite of the predicate.

```
(filter (complement yours?) mine)
;; => (c)
```

but I see no gain of that more verbose approach here.

If you know that you want a vector as a result, you can instead use [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into), passing in a `remove`ing transducer as argument.

```
(into [] (remove yours?) mine)
;; => [c]
```

Comment: Be careful using sets as predicates. It's very lovely in most cases, but if the set contains false or nil you will be surprised.

Comment: @amalloy This is a very nasty subtlety that didn't strike me but definitely a potential source of nasty bugs, thanks! I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes. I very much wish sets returned true/false instead of returning the item. Returning the item is great for maps, but for sets it provides no particular benefit and obscures potentially useful information.

Answer (score 0):

`contains?` is a horrible misnamer in Clojure in my view. (No, it does NOT check, whether an element is contained in a collection! It just checks whether for a key (an index or key) there exist a value in the collection.)

Use `some` in combination with `#{}` to check for membership in a collection!

```
(remove #(some #{%} yours) mine)
;; => (c)
```

Or:

```
(defn in? [coll x] (some #{x} coll))
(remove #(in? yours %)  mine) ;; => {c}
```